# Expand/Collapse Programmatically in Radgrid

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid

I am using RadGrid with Nested Hierarchy of Master/Detail Tables. I want to Expand the Master Row when the detail Table inside the row has few rows. I am trying to achieve the same using below code

```
  Private Sub RadGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles dbgView.ItemDataBound
  If <considtion to check if row is expanded>Then
      e.Item.Expanded = True
  End If
```

However even after setting the Expanded flag as True, if I check the value of the state in QuickWatch, it still remains False. Can someone help me understand why state for that specific row is not getting changed? If this is not the right way in changing the state programmatically, can someone let me know the alternate way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebind the grid after setting the Expanded property or simply move the condition in the Page_Load method. Just make sure that after the changing of the value, there is rebind or the NeedDataSource method is executed.
Hope these suggestions help.

Answer (score 0):

For resolving the issue , i used two hidden fields

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnExpandCollapse" Value="0" runat="server" />

 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnExpanded" Value="0" runat="server" />
```

Then the following two grid events are used to capture the state of the grid item

```
     /* Start functions used for collapse the grid  */
    protected void Grid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (GridDataItem item in Grid.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
             GridTableView DetailsTable = (GridTableView)item.OwnerTableView;

             System.Collections.Hashtable ht = DetailsTable.DataKeyValues[i];


            string strDataKey= ht["DataKey"].ToString();
            if (strDataKey == hdnExpandCollapse.Value)
                 {
                     if (hdnExpanded.Value == strDataKey)
                     {
                         item.Expanded = false;
                         hdnExpanded.Value = "0";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         item.Expanded = true;

                         hdnExpanded.Value = strDataKey;
                     }

                 }

                 i++;
        }
    }


    protected void Grid_ItemCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExpandCollapseCommandName)
        {
            hdnExpandCollapse.Value = ((EntityClass)(e.Item.DataItem)).DataKey.ToString();

        }
    }
    /* End functions used for collapse the grid  */
```

Reply